# Dynamic Method Addition Python Array

Tags: python, numpy

I have encountered a problem with the following code

```
def vdot(self, other):
    return np.sum(self@other, axis=0)

np.array.vdot = vdot
```

This code should allow me to use the vdot function as

```
a=np.matrix('1 0; 0 1')
V=np.array([a,a,a])
print(V.vdot(V))
```

which should give me a 2x2 matrix, which is just 3 times the unit matrix. The code should just multiply vectors that have matrices as entries. Though, if I try do define this function  with np.array.vdot = vdot, it gives me an error message "'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'vdot'". On the other hand, this works perfectly fine with matrices, see [Add method to numpy object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70073048/add-method-to-numpy-object/70197670)

Note that using vdot as vdot(array, array) works perfectly fine.

Why wouldn't this work on an array? Nothing seems to be different from the matrix case.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: are you sure its is not because you are not using the transpose of V like:

V.vdot(V.T) ?

Comment: Hi, no. The function cannot even be defined. The line "np.array.vdot = vdot" gives an error, meaning, before I get to use it. Also, the code works without transposing the vector.

Comment: `np.array` is function.  You can't add attributes or methods to a function.

Comment: `type(np.matrix)` gives `<class 'type'>` but `type(np.array)` gives `<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`. there is ndarray and `type(ndarray)` also gives `<class 'type'>` but if you try to assign function then it shows `built-in/extension type 'numpy.ndarray'` and it can means code in C/C++ and it can't have extensions like this.

Comment: `np.matrix` is a subclass definition written in python.  Thus is has a `__dict__` and can take additional methods as you did.  `np.array` is a compiled function that returns a `ndarray` object.  The `ndarray` class code is all compiled, and does not have this directory, so you can't add methods or attributes to numpy arrays.   numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.py` is the `matrix` source code.

Comment: The best you can do from my point of view is to wrap-up the np.array in class and make a custom method for your case.

Comment: @furas Thanks. I did not know the command type(). It wasn't obvious to me what the 'type' in <class 'type'> means, but I found this https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/, from where I understood that 'type' is just the "default type" of a class (rather than something more obvious like <class 'class'>).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class you are looking for is `np.ndarray`. `np.array` is just a function that helps to instantiate ndarrays. But as you will see if you try to monkey patch np.ndarray, it's not possible. This is as far as I understand because the ndarray type is written and compiled in C and behaves like a built-in.

Comment: Hi again @sunnytown. I see. Many thanks again!